# PHP redis lua script not working

Tags: php, lua, redis, phpredis

The script works on my MAC, the `phpinfo()` shows the php redis support version is: Redis Version   2.2.5

My script in PHP is:

```
$script
    = "
        local count = redis.call('incr',KEYS[1])
        if tonumber(count) == 1 then
            redis.call('expire',KEYS[1],ARGV[1])
        end
        return count";

//$sha1_value = $this->conn->script('load', $script);
//var_dump($sha1_value);
if (FALSE === $this->conn->evalSha('e03b35e8ef29c5c746b1791ec7ae89e19f52156c', [
        $key,
        1800
    ], 1)
)
{
    $this->conn->eval($script, [
        $key,
        1800
    ], 1);
}
```

The script not working on my server, on which the Redis version of PHP is 2.1.0.

The problem is the program meets the `$this->conn->script()` or `$this->conn->evalSha()` method will terminate the process, that's very odd, because no error log printed out, and when I write the code using the `try ... catch ...` way, the exception message did not printed out either.

I checked the official site of Redis it says:

`EVAL and EVALSHA are used to evaluate scripts using the Lua interpreter built into Redis starting from version 2.6.0.` (http://redis.io/commands/EVAL)

So I'm curious, because the redis-cli version on my server is already 2.8.0, and on my MAC is 3.0.2.

So how can I find out the problem?